# group by two different keys in js

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using reduce to group the information by the Id of each query.

```js
var data = [
   {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
   {Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
   {Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "545",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno", },
   {Id: "562", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "562",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno", },
   {Id: "562", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
   {Id: "562",  valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno", },
];

var data1 = [
   {Id: "552", valor:  "50.00", Descricao: "camisola", },
   {Id: "562", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "calças", },
];

var data2 = [
   {Id: "552", Responsavel: "antonio", },
   {Id: "545", Responsavel: "Pedro", },
   {Id: "562", Responsavel: "Amélia", },
   {Id: "562", Responsavel: "Maria", },
];

var results = data.concat(data1).concat(data2).reduce(function(results, item) {
        var id = item.Id || item.Id || item.Id; 
        (results[id] = results[id] || []).push(item);
        return results;
      }, {});
      
$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {
  var linha = ``;
  Object.keys(results).forEach(id => {
  Object.keys(results[id]).forEach(c => {
    Responsavel = results[id][c].Responsavel;
  })
    linha += `<p class="taman" style="text-align:left"> ${Responsavel}</p>
    
              <div class="teste">
              <table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover" border="1">
              
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Nº Recibo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Valor</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Descrição</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>                              
               <tbody>`;
    results[id].forEach(item => {
      var idValue = item.Id || item.Id;
      var valor = item.valor;
      var descricao = item.Descricao;
      linha += `<tr>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${idValue}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${valor}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${descricao}</td>
                 </tr>`;
    })
    linha += `</tbody></table></div>`;
  });
  $('#minhaDiv3').show();
  $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" href="s3" data-element="#minhaDiv3">Teste</button>

<section id="s3">
  <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv3">
    <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="btnPrint" style="text-align:right;">Print</button>

        <div class="row pagmfalta">

      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

If you noticed I have two people responsible for id `562`, Amélia and Maria.
But when I return the data, it only returns a table for Maria.
What I want is to return the same table twice, for Amelia and for Maria. As there are two different people in charge, I intend that in these cases, with more than one person in charge, it returns the same table as many times as necessary, according to the number of people in charge.

Comment: Moving the closing `})` in the `Object.keys(results[id]).forEach(c => {` iterator and adding a check for an `undefined` value in the assignment `results[id][c].Responsavel` fixes the issue of missing table for Amélia.

Answer (score 0):

You can group not only by id, but also by name. And use the resulting object from those fields as the key for the result.

```js
const arr = new Map();
rawRecords.forEach((rawRecord) => {
    const groupFieldsKey = JSON.stringify({id,name});
    const aggregatedValues = this._updateAggregateObject(rawRecord, arr.get(groupFieldsKey));
    arr.set(groupFieldsKey, aggregatedValues);
});
```

Okey. Let's coding a bit.

```js
const data = [
   {id: "552", value: "50.00", description: "Fraldas", },
   {id: "552", value: "35.00", description: "Creme", },
   {id: "545", value: "23.00", description: "Caneta", },
   {id: "545", value: "15.00", description: "Caderno", },
   {id: "562", value: "23.00", description: "Caneta", },
   {id: "562", value: "15.00", description: "Caderno", },
   {id: "562", value: "23.00", description: "Caneta", },
   {id: "562", value: "15.00", description: "Caderno", },
];

const data1 = [
   {id: "552", value: "50.00", description: "camisola", },
   {id: "562", value: "35.00", description: "calças", },
];

const data2 = [
   {id: "552", responsible: "antonio", },
   {id: "545", responsible: "Pedro", },
   {id: "562", responsible: "Amélia", },
   {id: "562", responsible: "Maria", },
];

const rawRecords = data.concat(data1).concat(data2);

const aggregateRawRecords = (recordsToProcess, accumulateObject, counter = 0) => {
    const copyAccumulateObject = {...accumulateObject
    };
    const notProcessedRawRecords = recordsToProcess.reduce((notProcessedResults, rawRecord) => {
        let processed = true;
        if (!rawRecord.responsible) {
            processed = !Object.keys(copyAccumulateObject)
            .filter(i => JSON.parse(i).id === rawRecord.id)
            .map(item => copyAccumulateObject[item].stuff.push({
                value: rawRecord.value,
                description: rawRecord.description,
            })).length ? false: true;
        } else {
            const groupFieldsKey = JSON.stringify({
                id: rawRecord.id,
                responsible: rawRecord.responsible,
            });
            copyAccumulateObject[groupFieldsKey] = {
                stuff: [],
            };
        }
        return processed ? notProcessedResults: [...notProcessedResults, rawRecord];
    },
    []);

    if (notProcessedRawRecords.length && !counter) {
        return aggregateRawRecords(notProcessedRawRecords, copyAccumulateObject, 1)
    } else {
        return Object.keys(copyAccumulateObject).map(item => {
            return {...JSON.parse(item),
                ...copyAccumulateObject[item]
            };
        });
    }
};

console.log(aggregateRawRecords(rawRecords, {}));
```

Comment: Can you apply your example with my code? I'm not understanding

Comment: @Anónimo and i wanted to ask a question.
```javascript
 var id = item.Id || item.Id || item.Id;
``` For what it?

Answer (score 0):

The `forEach` loop that assigns the variable `Responsavel` returns the last entry that contains a value for `results[id][c].Responsavel`. This is why a table for Maria was being rendered. She is the last entry in the object 'results["562"]'. The assignment of the variable `Responsavel` for Amélia was being overwritten by the assignment for Maria.

To fix this issue and to achieve the solution you're looking for (i.e. a table for Amélia and a table for Maria), move the closing `})` for the `forEach` iterator `Object.keys(results[id]).forEach(c => {` to after the line `linha +=` `;`.

In addition, add two lines to skip 'undefined' values in the `forEach` loop.

Here's your code with comments to identify the two added lines and the one moved line.

```js
var data = [{
    Id: "552",
    valor: "50.00",
    Descricao: "Fraldas",
  },
  {
    Id: "552",
    valor: "35.00",
    Descricao: "Creme",
  },
  {
    Id: "545",
    valor: "23.00",
    Descricao: "Caneta",
  },
  {
    Id: "545",
    valor: "15.00",
    Descricao: "Caderno",
  },
  {
    Id: "562",
    valor: "23.00",
    Descricao: "Caneta",
  },
  {
    Id: "562",
    valor: "15.00",
    Descricao: "Caderno",
  },
  {
    Id: "562",
    valor: "23.00",
    Descricao: "Caneta",
  },
  {
    Id: "562",
    valor: "15.00",
    Descricao: "Caderno",
  },
];

var data1 = [{
    Id: "552",
    valor: "50.00",
    Descricao: "camisola",
  },
  {
    Id: "562",
    valor: "35.00",
    Descricao: "calças",
  },
];

var data2 = [{
    Id: "552",
    Responsavel: "antonio",
  },
  {
    Id: "545",
    Responsavel: "Pedro",
  },
  {
    Id: "562",
    Responsavel: "Amélia",
  },
  {
    Id: "562",
    Responsavel: "Maria",
  },
];

var results = data.concat(data1).concat(data2).reduce(function(results, item) {
  var id = item.Id || item.Id || item.Id;
  (results[id] = results[id] || []).push(item);
  return results;
}, {});

$(document).on('click', '.dad-pagamento', function() {
  var linha = ``;
  Object.keys(results).forEach(id => {
    Object.keys(results[id]).forEach(c => {
      Responsavel = results[id][c].Responsavel;
      if (Responsavel === undefined) {
        return;
      } // <- Added this line to skip 'c' entries that have an 'undefined' 'Responsavel' property
      linha += `<p class="taman" style="text-align:left"> ${Responsavel}</p>
    
              <div class="teste">
              <table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover" border="1">
              
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Nº Recibo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Valor</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Descrição</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>                              
               <tbody>`;
      results[id].forEach(item => {
        if (item.Responsavel) {
          return;
        } // <- Added this line to skip 'item' containing the 'Responsavel' property
        var idValue = item.Id || item.Id;
        var valor = item.valor;
        var descricao = item.Descricao;
        linha += `<tr>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${idValue}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${valor}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${descricao}</td>
                 </tr>`;
      });
      linha += `</tbody></table></div>`;
    }); // <- Moved this closing bracket plus parenthesis to after 'linha +=' from after 'Responsavel = results[id][c].Responsavel;'
  });
  $('#minhaDiv3').show();
  $(".pagmfalta").html(linha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" href="s3" data-element="#minhaDiv3">
    Teste
</button>
<section id="s3">
  <div style="display:none" id="minhaDiv3">
    <button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item" id="btnPrint" style="text-align:right;">
            Print
        </button>
    <div class="row pagmfalta">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Original answer: The following code can be used to achieve the same table results.

To return the same table twice, for Amelia and for Maria, I used the following steps.

1. Concatenate the `data` and `data1` arrays.
2. Iterate the `data2` array.
3. Use the `filter` method on the `results` array.
4. Add an HTML table to the `.pagmfalta` div.

The code is written in plain JavaScript.

```js
var data = [
    { Id: "552", valor: "50.00", Descricao: "Fraldas", },
    { Id: "552", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "Creme", },
    { Id: "545", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
    { Id: "545", valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno", },
    { Id: "562", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
    { Id: "562", valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno", },
    { Id: "562", valor: "23.00", Descricao: "Caneta", },
    { Id: "562", valor: "15.00", Descricao: "Caderno", },
];

var data1 = [
    { Id: "552", valor: "50.00", Descricao: "camisola", },
    { Id: "562", valor: "35.00", Descricao: "calças", },
];

var data2 = [
    { Id: "552", Responsavel: "antonio", },
    { Id: "545", Responsavel: "Pedro", },
    { Id: "562", Responsavel: "Amélia", },
    { Id: "562", Responsavel: "Maria", },
];

var results = data.concat(data1);

document.querySelector(".dad-pagamento").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

function clickHandler() {
    // Sort person list by Id value
    data2.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.Id - b.Id;
    });

    data2.forEach(function (person) {
        var id = person.Id;
        var filteredData = results.filter(d => d.Id === id);
        addHtml(person.Responsavel, filteredData);
    });
}

function addHtml(responsavel, filteredData) {

    var html = "";

    html += `<p class="taman" style="text-align:left"> ${responsavel}</p>
    
              <div class="teste">
              <table class="align-middle mb-0 table table-borderless table-striped table-hover" border="1">
              
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center">Nº Recibo</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Valor</th>
                  <th class="text-center">Descrição</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>                              
               <tbody>`;

    filteredData.forEach(function (data) {
        html += `<tr>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${data.Id}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${data.valor}</td>
                   <td class="text-center text-muted"> ${data.Descricao}</td>
                 </tr>`;
    });

    html += `</tbody></table></div>`;

    document.querySelector(".pagmfalta").innerHTML += html;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" tabindex="0" class="dropdown-item btn-show dad-pagamento" href="s3" data-element="#minhaDiv3">Teste</button>
<div class="row pagmfalta"></div>
```